# How can I use "provide" global info in a composable file

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning Vue and I don't know which is the best way to do this:

Imagine I have an Application that needs 2 global states to work with so I use the `provide/inject` api:

```
createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .provide('state', state)
  .provide('apiUrl', 'http://localhost:3000')
  .mount('#app')
```

And imagine that i need those states in a composable to fetch an api or whatever

```
const apiUrl = inject('apiUrl')

export const fetchApi = () => {
    fetch(`${apiUrl}/whatever`, ...) // <--------- Here I need the apiUrl
 }
```

But if I inject the state outside a  tag, Vue throw this warn

```
[vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
```

If I need this state everytime i run this composable in a component, how can I inject the state?

I'm aware that I can pass this info as an argument but that means everytime I need this composable I need to `inject` the state in the component and then pass it as an argument, what I want to avoid is to call the `inject` api and let the composable have this info instead

I am aware as well that I can simply have the apiUrl in a constant in the composable.

The main thing here is: **Is there a way to call this info within a composable or any reusable code outside the setup option?**

Comment: Create a composeable that exposes a persistent state that you can bind these values to instead, and don't' use provide/inject, because it's against the design paradigm you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "inject the state outside a tag" - what does this mean? You're supposed to use inject() in the body of component setup

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `vite`, check out this document.
**https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode**

Create `.env` file and access `API_URL` where you want by `import.meta.env.API_URL`.